# Parallel child processes with fork() and pipe(): Bad file descriptor and unpredictable behaviour

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

I try to set up parallel calculations in processes instead of threads. I started with a very simple example: send an integer from parent process to child process. It works and this is the code of the function processParallel1():

```
//parent sends integer to child
bool processParallel1()
{
    //define pipe
    int parent2Child[2];

    //create pipe
    pipe(parent2Child);

    //fork
    pid_t child = fork();

    if(child == 0) //child process
    {
        //close not needed end of pipe
        close(parent2Child[1]);

        for(;;)
        {
            struct pollfd pfd;
            pfd.fd = parent2Child[0];
            pfd.events = POLLIN;

            //wait until data is available at the pipe
            if(poll(&pfd, 1, -1) < 0)
            {
                cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
                return false;
            }

            if((pfd.revents&POLLIN) == POLLIN)
            {
                int data;
                if(!readData1(parent2Child[0], data))
                    return false;

                cout << "c: received data: " << strerror(errno) << endl;

                cout << "data received: " << data << endl;

                if(data == -1)
                    break;
            }
        }

        exit(0);
    }
    else //parent process
    {
        //close not needed end of pipe
        close(parent2Child[0]);

        //send data to child
        if(!writeData1(parent2Child[1], 136758))
            return false;

        cout << "p: wrote data: " << strerror(errno) << endl;

        //send stop data
        if(!writeData1(parent2Child[1], -1))
            return false;

        cout << "p: wrote data: " << strerror(errno) << endl;

        //wait for child to end
        wait(nullptr);

        //close all pipes
        close(parent2Child[0]);
        close(parent2Child[1]);
    }

    return true;
}
```

In processParallel1() I use this methods for writing and reading to the pipe:

```
bool writeData1(int fd, const int data)
{
    int bytesWritten = write(fd, &data, sizeof(int));
    if(bytesWritten < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool readData1(int fd, int & data)
{
    char intBuf[sizeof(int)];
    int bytesRead = read(fd, intBuf, sizeof(int));
    if(bytesRead > 0)
    {
        data = *(int *)intBuf;
    }
    else if(bytesRead < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Everything works as expected. Now I add more data and it becomes strange. I only exchanged the methods for writing and reading (and created a new version of the method now named processParallel3()):

```
bool writeData3(int fd, const int number, const std::string text)
{
    int bytesWritten = write(fd, &number, sizeof(int));
    if(bytesWritten < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }

    int size = text.size() + 1;
    bytesWritten = write(fd, &size, sizeof(int));
    if(bytesWritten < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }

    bytesWritten = write(fd, text.c_str(), size);
    if(bytesWritten < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool readData3(int fd, int & number, std::string & text)
{
    char numberBuf[sizeof(int)];
    int bytesRead = read(fd, numberBuf, sizeof(int));
    if(bytesRead > 0)
    {
        number = *(int *)numberBuf;
    }
    else if(bytesRead < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }

    char sizeBuf[sizeof(int)];
    int size = -1;
    bytesRead = read(fd, sizeBuf, sizeof(int));
    if(bytesRead > 0)
    {
        size = *(int *)sizeBuf;
    }
    else if(bytesRead < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }

    char textBuf[size];
    bytesRead = read(fd, textBuf, size);
    if(bytesRead > 0)
    {
        text = std::string(textBuf);
    }
    else if(bytesRead < 0)
    {
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I run processParallel3() in a main I get three times a "Success" after writing and reading, but the methods hangs after printing the received data in the child.

When I add the method processParallel1() to be run directly before processParallel3() in 1 everything is ok, but now I get three times "Bad file descriptor" and it hangs again.

Any idea what could happen or what further tests I could run?

Comment: If `readData1` returns true, then the corresponding `read()` succeeded.  Then `errno` does not contain anything useful, so printing out `strerror(errno)` in that case is pointless and probably confusing.  Ditto for `writeData1`.

Comment: In particular, system calls generally do **not** set `errno` to 0 when they succeed; rather, they leave it unchanged.

Comment: Errors printed are caused by your `processParallel1` closing `parent2Child[0]` twice in the parent process.

Comment: Where is your `processParallel3`?

Comment: @NateEldredge: you are right, its only there for debugging, I tried to find out when and what is happening during the reads or writes

Comment: I fixed the double closing of the pipe. Currently I can run processParallel1() and processParallel3() after each other without the "Bad file descriptor". 

But it still hangs after printing "data received..."

I did not posted the code of processParallel3() because it is identical to processParallel1() besides the usage of readData3() instead of readData1() and similar for writeData. In former posts I was told not to post too much code ;)

Comment: I found the error. Thanks for pointing to that, @numzero. In processParallel3() I still wrote only the stop integer, but tried to read more data.